# Could isopropyl damage a PCB?

Tags: pcb, cleaning

I cleaned a PCB with isopropyl alcohol, 75%. When I turned it on, something strange happened.  The microcontroller GPIOs that drive the LEDs started to behave like they have relatively low resistance, enough to slightly light the LEDs, maybe around 0.5mA. The thing persists after a few days now.

I wonder whether it's because of the isopropyl.

Comment: Did the problem exist before cleaning with isopropyl alcohol? Which MCU it is, how it drives the LED in hardware, and how is the pin driven in software?

Comment: How did you clean it?  Did you immerse it and swish it around?  Did you scrub it with a brush with isopropyl?  Given that you were using a mix with 25% water, how did you dry it?

Comment: @Justme it was OK, MCU is a TI C2000, drives through a resistor, active high.

Comment: @TimWescott just used a brush, dried it with a hot air station :)

Comment: @TQQQ I suggest giving it some more drying time in a warm place like a sunlit window sill. Liquid can take a while to escape from places like under components.

Comment: Answer is yes, as it is in the realm of possibility.  As for what part of your cleaning process is to blame, more info is needed.  How hot was the air- scalding? How soft is the brush - enough to scratch?

Comment: Was it 99.99% isopropanol or some drug store garbage with additives sold as rubbing alcohol?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany the OP said `75%` ... could easily be 25% oil

Comment: Pure isopropanol will not damage PCBs unless they have speakers, microphones or anything similar mounted to them.

Comment: I will take a guess and say it was water damage. You state you used  isopropyl 75%, I am 99% sure the other 25% was water. Use the 90% + for cleaning, the more pure the better. Isopropyl has been the go to for cleaning PCBs on repair benches for at least 40 years. When it is clean dry it with a lint free cloth or wipe then let it set for at least 5 minutes. I also tap it on the counter sideways to knock the cleaner that gets under components out.  I cheat I also place a fan over them.

Comment: Right ^^^^ The problem was likely you used IPA with 25% water.    You can get nearly 99.9% pure IPA from the drug store for like $5/bottle.  I use it all the time, great for taking solder flux off.  Be careful, it's legit flammable as gasoline.

Comment: Actually, many 75% isopropyl have more than water in the other 25%. Many have scents and other products that may have contaminated the PCB. I'd try cleaning again with 99% isopropyl to try to remove any contamination.